# Terraform aws_api_gateway_integration_response keeps wanting to change attribute

Tags: terraform

Terraform aws_api_gateway_integration_response keeps wanting to change selection_pattern attribute. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "api_gateway_integration_response_e1_default" {
  rest_api_id       = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway_rest_api.id}"
  resource_id       = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.e1_api_gateway_resource.id}"
  http_method       = "${aws_api_gateway_method.e1_api_gateway_method.http_method}"
  status_code       = "${aws_api_gateway_method_response.api_gateway_method_response_e1_202.status_code}"
  selection_pattern = "-"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "api_gateway_integration_response_e2_default" {
  rest_api_id       = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway_rest_api.id}"
  resource_id       = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.e2_api_gateway_resource.id}"
  http_method       = "${aws_api_gateway_method.e2_api_gateway_method.http_method}"
  status_code       = "${aws_api_gateway_method_response.api_gateway_method_response_e2_202.status_code}"
  selection_pattern = "-"
}
```

My terraform apply output that keeps wanting to update.

```
terraform apply
...
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  ~ module.gateway.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.api_gateway_integration_response_e1_default
      selection_pattern: "" => "-"

  ~ module.gateway.aws_api_gateway_integration_response.api_gateway_integration_response_e2_default
      selection_pattern: "" => "-"


Plan: 0 to add, 2 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.
```

See terraform version

```
$ terraform version
Terraform v0.11.14
+ provider.aws v2.32.0
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this could be a bug. In the AWS console, before expanding an intergration response, an empty value for the selection pattern is displayed as a single dash `-`. However after expanding the integration response, the pattern is empty and the text `default` is displayed.

In the [AWS API Documents for the Selection Pattern paramter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration-response/#selectionPattern) there's no mention of being able to pass in a `-` to reset the pattern to default.

Setting `selection_pattern = ""` should get what you need. I tested it with Terraform 0.12.9. I confirmed this also works on Terraform 0.11.14